# remove decimal point but keep digits after

Tags: vb.net

If I have a decimal such as 89.33 and I would like to convert it to 8933 how would I go about doing this. I do not want it to round off, just drop the decimal point, thanks.

Comment: If it is always 2 decimal points then you could multiply it by 100. Otherwise you could convert it to a string, strip the `.`, and then convert it to an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a string then manipulate that.

```
Dim longVersion = (89.33).ToString.Replace(".", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the number to a String and then replace the period with an empty string.

```
Dim YourDecimalString As String = 89.33.ToString.Replace("."c, "")
```

Comment: You have a period (".") in the number, but you are trying to remove a comma (",") fro m the string.

Comment: I thought you would want to do that, but as you asked, I did made the change.

Comment: i have no idea where this seperate convo came from,l,